# Power Law fit giving a straight line

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am basically trying to do a power law fit to the following distance and acceleration arrays. However, the power law fit is basically giving me a straight line. Any help would be appreciated on how I can get a true power law relationship.

```
Dis= [0.2065 0.2661 0.2026 0.22   0.2065 0.2661 0.264  0.2173 0.2615 0.2682
 0.407  0.4085 0.409  0.4045 0.405  0.3985 0.5235 0.5846 0.5171 0.5385
 0.6415 0.7661 0.699  0.6523 0.7745 0.7332 0.842  0.9085 0.909  0.8445
 0.84   0.8635]

Acc= [-43.3  -3.  -86.8 -10.5 -56.2  -2.5  -7.2 -12.2  -4.6  -9.  -21.3  -2.
  -3.2  -2.7  -5.8  -6.8 -15.5  -1.8 -22.1  -0.5  -8.7  -0.8   0.   -3.3
  -0.8  -0.8 -12.5  -0.5  -0.7   0.3  -1.   -1.2] 

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def f(r, c0, m, c):
    return c0 + r**m * c
data= pd.read_table('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/File.txt', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
dis=r=data[:,0]
acc=data[:,1]
dis_min=np.min(dis)
dis_max=np.max(dis)
popt, pcov= curve_fit(f, dis, acc, p0 = np.asarray([-1, 10**5, 0]))
rr = np.linspace(dis_min, dis_max, len(dis))
aa = f(rr, *popt)
plt.xlabel('Distance (km)', fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel(' Acceleration (m/s-2)', fontsize=30)
plt.scatter(r, a, c='burlywood', s=10**2)
plt.plot(rr, aa, linewidth=3, label='Power law fit')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This combination of data and equation appears to be very sensitive to the initial parameter values for the non-linear solver used in curve_fit(). I have what appears to be a good fit with fitted values of:

```
c = -2.2896848166160833E-21
c0 = -5.0760537033961146E+00
m = -3.2529524073781118E+01
```

giving R-squared = 0.899 and RMSE = 5.83.

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me how to get the RMSE? Also, how you got this parameter choices?

Comment: For RMSE, I used these steps: A) error = predicted - actual B) sq_error = numpy.square(error) C) mse = numpy.mean(sq_error) D) rmse = numpy.sqrt(mse) and for the fitting I used my open source Python online curve fitter for this equation at http://zunzun.com/Equation/2/Power/Standard%20Power%20With%20Offset/ it uses a genetic algorithm named Differential Evolution to give the initial parameter values for curve_fit() so that I do not have to guess at them. Actually, I simply copy-and-pasted in your data and hit the Submit button.